# Tables from Wikipedia page

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I would need to get the tld from this table

```
tables = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains",header=0)
name_country_top_domains=tables[5][['Name[5]']]
country_name=tables[5][['Entity']]
```

i.e. the table of all countries:

But I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Name[5]'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you have a look at `tables[5]` once you've loaded it and see what columns it actually has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Name[7]` instead of `Name[5]`

```
tables = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains",header=0)
name_country_top_domains = tables[5][['Name[7]']]
country_name=tables[5][['Entity']]
```

Comment: May I ask you where I can find the name[7] when I inspect the wikipedia page?

Comment: ```Name[7]``` is the column name, because of some link reference to that column. If you look closely you can see that there's a ```[7]``` right by the name of the column ```Name```. It's possible that if the reference change, the name of the column change to something different like ```Name[8]```